# How can I uninstall Ubuntu 12.04/13.04?

Tags: uninstall

Is it possible to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04/13.04 and if so how?

I am currently dual booting it with Windows 7 (and it wasn't installed via Wubi and I ***don't*** have a system repair disk.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can unninstall by formatting the partition where Ubuntu is. You can do this by either downloading a partition manager software for Windows(like [Magic Partition Manager](http://partition-magic.soft32.com/)) or by using [gparted live-cd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). You maybe wil have to use Windows installatio disk to repair the boot of Windows or you can use a Ubuntu live cd and install grub again on the disk. Recommended the use of Windows installation disk.